# Does sleep hypnosis actually work for insomniacs?

Tags: research, treatment-options, insomnia, hypnosis, sleep-aids

**Has sleep hypnosis been researched and studied to be effective for helping one to fall asleep?**

How does it work exactly?

Answer (score 2):

> There are very few research data available on the efficacy
>   of hypnosis in the treatment of sleep disorders. Most of the
>   literature is limited to case reports or studies with such a
>   small sample that at times it is very difficult to interpret the
>   results. There is a major placebo effect, so uncontrolled
>   trials are of limited value.

http://www.annals.edu.sg/pdf/37VolNo8Aug2008/V37N8p683.pdf

Answer (score -4):

Well hypnosis doesn't actually work on everyone, believe me, I've tried it myself, but when dealing with sleep hypnosis, its probably the same outcome for someone who can't be succumbed by its hypnotic effect. Now concerning insomnia, I would advice resisting coffee, and taking warm almond milk before bed, since it's also an excellent source of calcium, which can help the brain produce melatonin.

But when dealing with a person who can be succumbed by sleep hypnosis, such a person might be susceptible to its side effects which are anxiety, headache and even sometimes worsening the insomnia. Don't get me wrong, it is actually one way to induce sleepiness but I'm only telling you its possible side effects.

The last time I had insomnia, the two things I had to do was firstly to listen to soothing music, and resist checking the time, because checking time often will increase the stress and makes me start worrying if I'm ever going to sleep. So for now, my advice for you will be to listen to soothing music and most importantly resist checking your clock, mine lasted for up to 2 wks but when i used this method, within 1 and a half week, it was gone

http://www.helpguide.org/articles/sleep/cant-sleep-insomnia-treatment.htm

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Stack exchange is a Q&A network and operates in a somewhat different way than a forum. On health SE reliable references are required to back up the answers, since they are the only way in which the community can assess the answer regardless of the reader's background. We look for proven claims rather than personal experience or opinion. You can always [edit] your answer to add references. For more information on site policies please take our [tour] or visit the [help] or [meta]. Thanks!